# Machine monitoring application ( mysql )

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures, scada

I am building a monitoring application for a machine, position must be read and stored every second for a period of a month. I wrote a procedure to fill a table with initial 0 value.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(start_date datetime, end_date datetime)
BEGIN

DECLARE interval_var INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE end_date >= start_date DO

        INSERT INTO table1(datetime, value) VALUES(start_date, 0);
        SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL interval_var SECOND);

    END WHILE;

END
```

This process is very slow, and most of the time the connection with the sql database is lost. For example, when I try to fill the table from "2016-01-14 07:00:00" to "2016-01-15 07:00:00" the procedure reached 2016-01-14 07:16:39 and crashed due to lost connection with database.

Is there a more efficient way to create a template table for a month with second increments and 0 values? My monitoring application is built on vb.net and I have tried to create a code on vb to create this template table, but it was slower and more likely to crash than direct procedure on mysql workstation.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a prepared query, which is designed to be prepared once and run multiple times. Though your stored procedure should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the application architecture first. Expecting the whole system to run without failing for even 1 second for an entire month is asking an awful lot. Also, try to think about if you really need this much data.

1 record/sec*3600 sec/hr*24 hr/day*30 day/mo is more than 3.1 million records. Trying to process that much information will cause a lot of software to choke.

If the measurement is discrete, you may be able to cut this dramatically by only recording changes in the database. If it's analog, you may have no choice.

I would recommend creating two separate applications: a local monitor that stores local data, and then reports to the mysql server application every hour or so. That way, if the database is unavailable, it keeps right on collecting data, and when the database is available again, it can transfer everything that has been recorded since the last connection. Then the mysql application can store the data in the database in one shot. If that fails, it can retry, and keep it's own copy of the data until it gets stored into the database.

Ex:

machine => monitoring station app => mysql app => mysql database

It's a little more work, but each application will be pretty small, and they may even be reusable. And it will make troubleshooting much easier, and dramatically increase the fault tolerance in the system.